# AppleScript: "Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier", Mavericks error?

Tags: applescript

I have a short script that I started working on where I want Spotify to search for a specific song once an AppleScript is running, but I get this error that seems to be something that only Mavericks is whining about (after a short round of googling).

```
tell application "Spotify" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "Spotify" to keystroke "l" using command down
```

It says

> *Syntax Error: **Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier***

and pointing to "using". Now, I've only been coding for a short period, but to my knowledge, this is the exact syntax that tons of people are using and have been posting to SO and other places.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The command `keystroke` belongs to the Processes Suite. You can call it with System Events.

```
tell application "Spotify" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Spotify"
    keystroke "l" using command down
end tell
```

Comment: How would you go about to make an if statement with a keystroke then?

Comment: Your second answer is better... You should not nest tell application "System Events" within tell application "Spotify".

Comment: @Erik You can make an if statement in the tell app "System Events" block more info: [if Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-158244)